# How to autoplay the saavan link in html audio tag?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I have  welcome.html file in that i have one audio tag inside that source attribute i am adding link from the `jio-saavan` but it's not playing when the webpage is opened but in console i am getting following error..

`Error on console`

```
welcome.html:28 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.
```

```
<audio  autoplay id="my_audio">
  <source src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=11wfYWiukbIZJQnDL385jQs2SGQA5ESbL" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<script>
document.getElementById('my_audio').play();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you clearly that you can't start an audio (or even a video if not muted) if the user haven't interacted with the page before.

Some links to better help you understand the policy on autoplay:

- https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/
- https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#autoplay_availability

Comment: is there any other way to play that audio in background